# Django Channels Execution Order

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

I need some help understanding how Django Channels is executing the code. I'm probably missing some understanding of sync vs async as it's not doing what I would expect.

In summary I wanted a consumer that would do the following:

1. Connect
2. On message from client

   - in a while loop:

     - execute a long running function (1 sec)
     - call `group_send` broadcasting results

This wasn't working, so I tried to create a very simple consumer to understand what's happening.

I create a `WebsocketConsumer` as I think I want it to run `syncronously`, i.e. I want each loop to execute and then broadcast the results, then execute again.

When I trigger the receive method I see the `self.send` happen instantly, but both the *"2. First Group Call"* and the *"3. Second Group Call"* happen after the long running function. I can see from the timestamps in the `console.log` that the `chat_message()` is only being executed for the *"2. First Group Call"* after the long running function, even  though it appears before the long running function in the `receive` method.

The results in one of the browser console is:

1. received "1. Self send **21:45:22.060500**"
2. received "2. **21:45:22.060500** first group call chat start: 21:45:24.529500"
3. received "3. **21:45:22.060500** second group send lrf start_time: 21:45:22.348000 lrf end_time: 21:45:24.349500 chat start: 21:45:24.537000"

The timestamps in bold are the timestamp when the receive method was started.
The *"chat start"* timestamp is when chat_message method is called.

```
class MyConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    groups = ["my_group"]

    def connect(self):
        print("connected")
        self.accept()

    def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
        ts = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")

        self.send(text_data=json.dumps("1. Self send {}".format(ts)))

        text_data = "2. {} first group call".format(ts)
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            "my_group",
            {
                "type": "chat.message",
                "text": text_data,
            },
        )
        text_data = self.long_running_function(ts)
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            "my_group",
            {
                "type": "chat.message",
                "text": text_data,
            },
        )

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        print("disconnected")
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)("my_group", self.channel_name)

    def chat_message(self, event):
        chat_msg_start_time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")
        text_data = "{} chat start: {}".format(event["text"], chat_msg_start_time)
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps(text_data))

    def long_running_function(self, ts):
        start_time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")
        time.sleep(2)
        end_time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")
        msg = "3. {} second group send lrf start_time: {} lrf end_time: {}".format(ts, start_time, end_time)
        return msg
```